# Remove Program from Add/Remove Program List after Install Wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation, registry

I am currently developing a windows application that will be used for multiple clients but will use a central application. The idea is that multiple clients could have their version of the application installed, but in secret they would all use this central app, so what I need to do is install the central application but remove it from the uninstall a program list then afterward install the client specific program so that the user only will see the client specific program installed. (hopefully that made sense and wasn't too wordy)

So basically I want to programmatically remove a program from the uninstall program list after it has been installed with Wix. I am encountering the following problems and have the following questions:

- Where is the Wix installer placing the registry key for the uninstall a program list? I've looked in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall as well as HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and could not find the uninstall registry key that corresponded to the installed app.
- Is there anyway to consistently get the hash or name the key corresponding to the item in the uninstall list? So I can consistently remove it?
- Does this location vary at all with version of windows?
- Is there anyway to stop the installer from placing this registry key in the first place?

Comment: Try HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: Why not just set ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT during the install of your secret MSI? That will hide it from Programs&Features.

Comment: @PhilDW thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed, I honestly didn't think it would be that simple because I've spent hours searching for a solution like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT during the install of your secret MSI? That will hide it from Programs&Features.